# SyntaxError in CasperJS when edited through WinSCP

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, casperjs, winscp

I have a problem with a casperjs script :

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
console.log("casper create OK");

casper.start("https://my-ip/login_page.html", function() {

    console.log("Connexion URL OK");

    // set a wait condition to make sure the page is loaded (particularly iframe in my case) 
    this.wait(5000,function(){
        console.log("Attente 5 sec OK");

        //fill out the form 
        this.fillSelectors("form[name='lf']",{
            'input#user' : "my_login",
            'input#pass' : "my_password"
        });

        console.log("Renseignement login et pass OK");

        // click the login button 
        this.click("input[name='loginsub']");
        console.log("Passage bouton login OK");

        // switch to iframe (won't be necessary for most)
        this.page.switchToChildFrame('mainframe');
        console.log("Switch iframe OK");

        // Test d'une zone sur la page pour valider la connexion
        casper.waitForSelector('.area-status', function() {
            console.log("Validation element sur la page OK");
        });
    }); 
});

// Check etat de l'alarme général
// Check status des zones de l'alarme
casper.run();
```

When I launch my script, I have this error :

```
[root@srv-linux bin]# casperjs script.js
SyntaxError: Parse error
```

When I check my script on http://esprima.org/demo/validate.html I say all is OK (no error syntax).

This error happens when I change the script through WinSCP.

Can you help me?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. I copied the script and it runs. There is no syntax error. Do you see any output?

Comment: no I d'ont have any output :(

Comment: It seems that you changed some things like the IP, maybe there lies the problem. Is your file UTF-8 encoded?

Comment: Thanks, yes the problem is my file ! When i create the file with winscp the script doesn't work ! When I use nano and I paste words it's work ! Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

Your script doesn't have a syntax error.

It seems that the configured WinSCP editor has a problem with encoding UTF-8 characters in such a way that they are preserved when saved to the server. You should use a good editor like Notepad++ through WinSCP. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to open the preferences and change the editor:

[image]

Comment: Without text transfer mode?

Comment: Why didn't you said so to begin with`?

Comment: Force text transfert is actived and not external editor. When I configure winscp like your screenshot I don't can save the file...